# A 1990s horror anthology book with a story about a group of boys watching a snuff movie

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for a book that I read when I was younger. It was a 90’s horror anthology book.  The particular story that I’m looking for was about a group of teenage boys. They go to a local video rental store to rent a snuff movie. Whilst there, they come across another young boy who goes back to the house with them to watch the movie.

> It transpires that the woman killed in the movie is his mother and he is a ghost.

If anyone could tell me the name of the story I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

"Video Nasty", by Phillip Pullman.  The anthology I have containing it is "Ghost Stories", chosen by Robert Westall, published 1988 by Kingfisher Books

Key quotes to support it:

> [The boy:] "I always watch it. That's the only time I see her.  I like
>  seeing my mum."
>
>  ...
>
>  "They killed her and then they set fire to the house.  It all burnt
>  up, the baby and all.  That was me, that was, that baby"